# How to learn magento

Tags: php, magento

Hi I want to learn Magento, I am doing PHP for almost 2 years learn CMS and framework. Now want to learn Magento but I do not found any solid source to understand functionality and DB structure of magento. If any one can give me some books name or good article that will be very helpful thanks..

Comment: Learn it with a tutorial.

Comment: @relentless thanks for obvious answer Mr obvious.

Comment: Here, I'll even give you a link https://www.google.com/#q=learn+magento

Comment: http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/_media/doc/magento---sample_database_diagram.png

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way to learn Magento is to solve issues as you go along. Maybe a good place to start is this:
http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base.
Also the guys at siteground did a nice thing with this: http://www.siteground.com/tutorials/magento/
Other than this, maybe you should actually start working on a task and when you hit a brick wall (this should happen very fast), just see how other people solved the issues.
As for database structure, maybe you should read about the [EAV paradigm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93attribute%E2%80%93value_model). This is how the products, categories and customers are stored in the DB.
If you insist on a database structure [here it is](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/2_-_magento_concepts_and_architecture/magento_database_diagram)...but good luck with that.